# the instance variable isnt getting modified in python

Tags: python, class, methods

the instance variable `tim` an empty list, in class `FridgeScreen` isnt getting modified when i modify it in the method `search_recipe`. i know that because when i print the variable in another class `RecipeScreen` it prints out an empty list.

**MAIN.PY**:

```
import pandas as pd
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem

Builder.load_file('design.kv')
Window.size = (300, 500)

fridge_items = []
class FridgeScreen(Screen):
    tim = []

    def add_item(self):
        global lst
        i = 0
        fridge_items.append(self.ids.inp.text)
        self.ids.inp.text = ''
        for x in range(len(fridge_items)):
            lst = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=fridge_items[i])
            i += 1
        self.ids.list.add_widget(lst)

    def search_recipe(self):
        book = pd.read_csv('RECIPE_BOOK.csv')
        ingredients = book['Ingredients']
        recipe_chodh = book.drop(columns='Recipe')
        lst2 = []
        recipe_freq = {}

        for items in fridge_items:
            for ill in ingredients:
                if items in ill:
                    lst2.append(ill)

        for recipe in lst2:
            if recipe in recipe_freq:
                recipe_freq[recipe] += 1
            else:
                recipe_freq[recipe] = 1

        top_recipe = sorted(recipe_freq.items(),
                            key=lambda kv: kv[1],
                            reverse=True)

        z = 0
        for items in top_recipe:
            tommy = recipe_chodh[recipe_chodh['Ingredients'] == top_recipe[z][0]].index.values
            foo = recipe_chodh['Name'][int(tommy)]
            self.tim.append(foo)
            z += 1


class RecipeScreen(Screen):
    def add_lst(self):
        a = 0
        for it in range(len(self.fridge_screen.tim)):
            pluto = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text=self.fridge_screen.tim[a])
            self.ids.recipe.add_widget(pluto)
            a += 1

        print(self.fridge_screen.tim)
    
class My(RecipeScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()


class RootScreen(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    my = My()

    def build(self):
        return RootScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

and here's the .kv file if you dont get what is happening

**DESIGN.KV**:

```
<FridgeScreen>:
    Screen:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            MDToolbar:
                title: 'KITCHEN'
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x : print(x)]]
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                padding: 10

                MDTextField:
                    id: inp
                    hint_text: 'enter your ingredients'
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        id: list

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                padding: 10
                spacing: 80
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: 'search for recipes'
                    on_press: root.search_recipe()
                    on_press: root.recipe_screen.add_lst()
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'recipe_screen'

                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    icon: "plus"
                    on_press: root.add_item()

<RecipeScreen>:
    id: recipe_screen
    Screen:
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: recipe


<RootScreen>:
    FridgeScreen:
        recipe_screen: recipe_screen
        id: fridge_screen
        name:
            'fridge_screen'
    RecipeScreen:
        id: recipe_screen
        fridge_screen: fridge_screen
        name:
            'recipe_screen'
```

Comment: The way you've declared it, `tim` is _not_ an instance variable -- it's a _class_ variable, shared among all instances of the class.

Comment: Although even as a class attribute, it should still be mutated unless it's being reset somewhere. If it's never added to, that suggests `if items in ill:` is never true.